# Unable to convert NSDictionary values to json

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, nsjsonserialization

I have NSDictionary values that i want to convert it to Json string like:

```
{
    body = "10-feb";
    comments =     (
    );
    complete = 1;
    "created_at" = "2014-02-09T15:56:01Z";
    "due_at" = "2014-01-10 20:00:00 +0000";
    "due_on" = "2014-10-02";
    id = 439824;
    "notification_sent" = 0;
    "notify_user" = 0;
    "organization_id" = 972;
    participants =     (
    );
    reminders =     (
    );
    starred = 0;
    "updated_at" = "2014-02-09T15:56:01Z";
    "user_id" = 11129;
}
```

And the way i am converting it to json is:

```
- (NSString*) jsonStringWithPrettyPrint:(BOOL) prettyPrint str:(NSDictionary *)str {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:str
                                                       options:(NSJSONWritingOptions)    (prettyPrint ? NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted : 0)
                                                         error:&error];

    if (! jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"jsonStringWithPrettyPrint: error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        return @"{}";
    } else {
        return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    }
}
```

I dont know why it always fails to convert.?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Is `due_at` an `NSDate`?

Comment: yeah its an NSDate..i have added exceptional break point as well..it stop but i tried pressing continue to get a stack trace in the console but nothing logs and error remains nil.

Comment: is this a typo??? `options:(NSJSONWritingOptions)    (prettyPrint ? NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted : 0)`

Comment: I don't believe it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objects passed into `NSJSONSerialization` can only contain `NSDictionary`, `NSArray`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, or `NSNull`.

`NSDate` objects must be explicitly converted to `NSStrings` first using an `NSDateFormatter`.

Comment: converted date string to `NSString` with `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", date]` and problem gone :)

Comment: Your problem creating the JSON data is gone. But someone has to process the data. Check your documentation to find out what they are expecting. BTW. You could much easier call [myDate description].